# AWS Lambda and Mongo DB causing the following error: Cursor Session id is not same as the operation context's session id

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I am a novice to AWS Lambda, and I'm currently working on a messaging service that works using the producer-consumer model, where the Producer is Lambda api which receives requests and pushes them to AWS SQS for asynchronous processing, and my consumer is also a lambda function that consumes batch of messages from SQS to process. In my Lambda env, I have in place a MongoDB connection to log the messages to my DB. The MongoDB connection file follows a Singleton class design pattern to utilize warm connections, and is not made thread-safe because Javascript is inherently single threaded.

When I tried to Load Test the project using Apache Jmeter, using approx 100 threads for 30 minutes, I started receiving this error from Mongo.

`Cursor session id (048689af-01e4-4b61-982e-014d7ec11ed2 - x4oVKissGT3GHitCLZ6gIt34mKp9Lcfhm1vvXNV7jt0=) is not the same as the operation context's session id (none)`

I looked around and found out that this  could be because of following two issues:

if the cursor was created in a different transaction or if the operation context's session has expired.

I am not using any transaction in my code and I have no idea about the operation context sessions. So I have not been able to figure out why am I getting this error. Can someone help me??